# Python Plotly: adjusting pie chart size on a map

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I want to plot on a map pie charts representing some products frequency. I use plotly for that. I looked at the different proposals made by the community on the subject and i went to use [this solution](https://community.plotly.com/t/plotting-pie-charts-on-a-map/1779). The issue is that i do not understand how to reduce/adjust my pie chart size as you will see in the code below.

```
fig = go.Figure()

# Add trace
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(values=[17674,12279,11963,10384,5858],labels=['Meals','Processed proteins','Bakery','Snacks','Vegetables'], domain_x=(0.1, 0.3), domain_y=(0.2, 0.4))
)
fig.update_traces(showlegend=False,selector=dict(type='pie'))
# Add images
fig.add_layout_image(
        dict(
            source="path_to_blank_map",
            # xref="x",
            # yref="y",
            x=0,
            y=1.2,
            sizex=1.8,
            sizey=2,
            opacity=0.5,
            layer="below")
)

# Set templates
fig.update_layout(template="plotly_white",height=800,width=1200)

fig.show()
```

I tried to find if there is a way to update a trace size within the add_trace or the update_trace method but it seems impossible. The update_layout method increase or decrease size for the whole graph object and not for specific traces.
Any help would be welcome!!! Thanks a lot!